# Bluetooth automatic mouse connection not working

Tags: 14.04, mouse, bluetooth

I'd like my HP Bluetooth Mouse x4000b (no usb dongle) to connect automatically when starting my HP laptop (Ubuntu 14.04), but I can't succeed in it : I'm forced to do it manually by clicking the *connect* button.
I know this topic has been answered many times, but no solution worked for me.

Here's what I tried so far :

- Creating the file `/etc/default/bluetooth` with lines :

  ```
  HIDD_ENABLED=1
  HIDD_OPTIONS="--connect F0:65:DD:7D:EC:A0 --server"
  ```
- Putting `hciconfig hci0 reset` at the end of `/etc/init.d/bluetooth`
- Putting

  ```
  /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
  sleep 1
  /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
  ```

  in `/etc/rc.local`

None of these solution worked, I've read a lot of topics but couldn't find a solution ... that's why I'm asking that here, hoping you can help me troubleshooting that.

**Update:**

```
ray@ray-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ hciconfig 
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
BD Address: F8:16:54:02:9F:62  ACL MTU: 1021:5  SCO MTU: 96:5
UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
RX bytes:4672039 acl:306914 sco:0 events:6516 errors:0
TX bytes:36591 acl:372 sco:0 commands:401 errors:0

ray@ray-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ bluez-simple-agent hci0 F8:16:54:02:9F:62
Creating device failed: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed: Page Timeout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK To run at start up please, open start up applications from dash and choose new. Name it whatever you want and in the command box copy

```
sudo hidd --connect F0:65:DD:7D:EC:A0
```

Save it reboot, cross your fingers.

Comment: Thanks, but I've read this guide already and it doesn't match my needs (my mouse is already paired, plus it have no dongle).
And even when I try it, the trusted and connect commands seem to be unknown and it doesn't work

Comment: Okay, thanks for the precision.
But as I said, when I try, this doesn't work ...

ray@ray-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 F8:16:54:02:9F:62
Creating device failed: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed: Page Timeout

Comment: sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 F8:16:54:02:9F:62 This is not the correct command sudo bluez-simple-agent connect F8:16:54:02:9F:62 is what I said to use

Comment: Well it doesn't work either ... :(

ray@ray-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ sudo bluez-test-input connect F8:16:54:02:9F:62
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bluez-test-input", line 37, in <module>
    device = adapter.FindDevice(args[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.bluez.Error.DoesNotExist: Does Not Exist

Comment: So this isthe error from the command sudo bluez-simple-agent connect F8:16:54:02:9F:62

Comment: OK install this sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.3

Comment: Sorry that is 4 diffrent commands each time it says sudo is a new one

Comment: Thanks, I figured that.
So I downloaded Python3.3, changed the link of /usr/bin/python, ran the command again, and now it says :   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ImportError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'

Comment: You seem to have done your research before, please do tell me if this is just retracing your previous efforts and we can come at this from another angle maybe

Comment: Actually it's the first time that I try to run these python commands. I've tried other stuff, like those I put in the question, but nothing worked.
It seems that there's a problem with python-dbus, but removing it or re-installing it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it does exactly match this file (I tried with diff).

Comment: Yes, I have that file.

Comment: ray@ray-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/fit-dev$ sudo hidd --connect F8:16:54:02:9F:62
Can't get device information: No route to host

Doesn't work ... thanks for your time :)

Comment: I did, and the result is the same, no matter if the bluetooth if started, stopped, etc

Comment: Same, no route to host :(

Comment: This is very strange please leave it with me I will get back to you later today, we will try again

Comment: Can you try this revised connect command please bluez-simple-agent hci0 F8:16:54:02:9F:62

Comment: If it wont work run hciconfig and confirm hci0 is your device

Comment: Then run -  hcitool scan - and confirm 
F8:16:54:02:9F:62 is the MAC address you could post the output frome these two commands in you question for easy access and others to read

Comment: This is strange, because hcitool scan finds nothing now, but the mouse is connected. And the MAC address is the right one.

`ray@ray-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
ray@ray-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$`

Comment: Are you putting your mouse in discover mode as you run this

Comment: Right, I forgot that, sorry.
Now I don't understand anymore : hciconfig is giving me the address F8:16:54:02:9F:62 and

`ray@ray-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/fit-dev$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
 F0:65:DD:7D:EC:A0 HP Bluetooth Mouse X4000b`

gives another address ... why ?

So when I do `sudo hidd --connect F0:65:DD:7D:EC:A0` it works ...

Comment: It looks like we just confused the mac address with the devise address yesterday

Comment: Did you try the new answer ?

Comment: Maaaaaan it's working now.
Thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply though I went between dell and logitech support to find out why my logitech BT mice never autoconnect back to the systems and nobody ever supports it. I had to learn the hard way. Maybe this isn't helpful just figured I'd share my hard learned lesson.

None of my BT devices every connect to any OS/Device other than tablets/cell phones automatically. I've found rule of thumb is I have to unpair/remove the device from the OS/system then reconnect as after the device connects to another device it won't autoconnect to device one after it's most recent connection was device two.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your BT mouse and add it again assigning "0000" PIN for pairing, do not use default or auto PIN option. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `blueman-manager`. Probably you need to install it using `apt-get install blueman`.

Install it by use your Terminal， Run ”sudo apt-get install blueman“ This is a bluetooth manege program.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what “blueman-manager” is, how to install and use it (to resolve OP's issue)? (see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer))